# Codeigniter Subdomain Redirect - Controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain, cpanel

I want to be directed to the controller that I specified when I logged in with the subdomain.

for example

```
www.mysite.com -> mysite.com/main_controller

abc.mysite.com -> mysite.com/sub_controller
stack.mysite.com -> mysite.com/sub_controller
test.mysite.com -> mysite.com/sub_controller

www.mysite.com/other_controller -> mysite.com/other_controller
```

How can I direct subdomains like this?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not use Wildcard, I use fake subdomains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to play with htaccess, we can do some tricks. find below.

Create new folder inside the root folder (where you have installed the **application** and **system** folders).

Here i'm calling `subdomain` is the new folder for this case. So your root directory should like this.

```
/application
/system
/subdomain
/.htaccess
/index.php
/..
```

Then copy `/index.php` & paste it inside the `/subdomain` directory and change sub settings like below

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
$view_folder = '../application/views';
```

then, add this code in your `/application/config/routes.php`

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'mysite.com'){
    $route['default_controller'] = 'main_controller';   
}else{
    $route['default_controller'] = 'sub_controller'; 
}
```

-OR-

```
switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ) {
    case 'abc.mysite.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "sub_controller";
    break;
    case 'stack.mysite.com':
    case 'test.mysite.com':
        $route['default_controller'] = "sub_controller_2";
    break;
    default:
        $route['default_controller'] = 'main_controller';
}
```

finally, point your `subdomain` (ex. abc.mysite.com) to `/subdomain` directory

you do it with other method too, if you need refer following links.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter--net-16330
http://asvignesh.in/dynamic-subdomain-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Thank you but htaccess settings?

Comment: And I do not want URL Change

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: @user3030909 I have updated the answer, please check it. I hope you will get the answer..